# Vuejs replace big number on 99+

Tags: vue.js

I have a code:

```
<span class="pl-2 text-def" v-show="notificationsCount">@{{notificationsCount}}</span>
```

If `notificationsCount` number is 1000+ I need replace on `99+`. How I can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own [filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html):

```js
Vue.filter('bigNumber', function (value) {
  if (!value) { 
    return 0;
  }
  return value > 1000 ? '99+' : value;
});

new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    num1: 1001,
    num2: 999,
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <div>num1: {{ num1|bigNumber }}</div>
  <div>num2: {{ num2|bigNumber }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replacing

```
{{notifications}}
```

by

```
{{notifications < 1000 ? notifications : '99+'}}
```